# Can not reload page after form submit using Jquery and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am facing one issue. I can not reload the page/form using `Jquery/PHP`. I am explaining my code below.

> map.php;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="" role="form" id="frmMappingZone" name="frmMappingZone">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidAction" name="hidAction"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="" class="control-label" style="text-align:left;">Select Exam
                        Group:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control cmbExamGroup" name="cmbExamGroup" id="cmbExamGroup"
                            data-live-search="true">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="" class="control-label" style="text-align:left;">Select
                        Zone:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <select class="form-control cmbZone" name="cmbZone" id="cmbZone"
                            data-live-search="true">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <label for="" class="control-label" style="text-align:left;">Examination
                    Centres:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 well" style="max-height:220px;overflow-y: auto;">
                <div class="row" id="examCentreGroup"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-info tooltips" type="submit" id="btnSave" name="btnSave"
                        title="Save">Add
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end row -->

</form>
```

> map.js:

```
var centreArray = new Array();
$("input:checkbox[name='chkCentre[]']:checked").not("[disabled]").each(function () {
    centreArray.push($(this).val());
});

if (centreArray.length < 1) {
    $("#btnSave").prop('disabled', false);
    //toastr.error('Please Add some centre for Zone mapping.');
}

var cmbExamGroup = $("#cmbExamGroup").val();
var cmbZone = $("#cmbZone").val();
var oper = $("#btnSave").html();
if (oper == 'Add')
    toper = 'ADD_ZONE_MAPPING';
else if (oper == 'Update')
    toper = 'UPDATE_ZONE_MAPPING';
var institutedata =
    {
        cmbExamGroup: cmbExamGroup,
        cmbZone: cmbZone,
        centreArray: centreArray
    };
//ajax call to server
$.ajax({
    url: "exam_zone_mapping_db.php?type=" + toper + "&_s=" + session,
    //url:"exam_zone_mapping_db.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: institutedata,
    //cache: false,
    //contentType: false,
    //processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        //alert(response);
        $('#dtblCentreZone').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        //console.log('res',response);
        var result = JSON.parse(response);
        location.reload(true);
        if (result.dbStatus == 'SUCCESS') {

            $('#frmMappingZone').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm(true);

            toastr.success(result.dbMessage);
            if (oper == 'UPDATE_ZONE_MAPPING') {

                $('#modalZoneGroup').modal('hide');
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        else {
            toastr.error(result.dbMessage);
        }
        $('#modalCentreGroup').modal('hide');
        if (response == "Error") {
            toastr.error('Error in record insert.');
        }
        else {

        }
    },
    error: function () {
        toastr.error('We are unable to process please contact support');
    }
```

Here My data is inserting into database and I need to reload the page after submitting the form which is not happening. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: If you need to reload the page after submitting the form using AJAX, there's absolutely no point using AJAX at all.

Comment: Your form has no action

Comment: I have not posted the total code. Its like `$('#frmMappingZone').bootstrapValidator({.......})`.

Comment: you can use location.reload on your success callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.location.reload();
```

or

```
window.location.reload();
```

And your else statement in **success** has no meaning.